# Can A Div be in a form in HTML5

Tags: html

```html
<form class="form-1">
  <label for="username" class="label1"> Username:</label>
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="username"
    placeholder="eg Herny Hart"
    id="name-input"
    required>
  <label for="email" class="label2"> Enter your Email: </label>
  <input
    type="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="hernyhart10@gmail.com"
    id="email-input"
    required>
  <label for="number">2fa Verification If required:</label>
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="number"
    placeholder="239578"
    id="2fa-input">  
<label>
    <div>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
      <input id="submit2" type="submit" value="Sign-up">
    </div>


</form>
```

I don't know if it is ok to put a div container inside a HTML5 form container or is it wrong.
Am new to coding i need help to complete my animation project

Comment: prefer to use `<button>`, and it will save you from having to use a div

Comment: You can run your code through an HTML validator like https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 4):

Use MDN for questions like this. For this case, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), and find the "Permitted content" section:

> Permitted content: Flow content, but not containing `<form>` elements.

If you then click "Flow content" and read through the list, you'll see that `div` is listed as "Flow content":

```
. . .
<dfn>
<div>
<dl>
. . .
```

So yes, `div`s are allowed inside of `form`s.

Comment: Thanks, I do so.  since am new to coding I did not know I could use MDN to find answers to my  questions

Comment: @AvwerosuoTrustOgaga If you're getting into web development, MDN will become your Bible. You'll likely have it open in a tab at all times. For anything related to HTML, CSS, or JS, MDN is really the best source there is (besides the official specs, but they're a bit dense to go through as a newbie). I've been doing web development off and on for ~5 years now and I still consult it daily.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely fine to put a DIV inside of a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your HTML code by uploading it in W3C validator, keep the link, and it will be helpful for future, run every time if you are hesitating.
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `div` can a part in a form also. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> div</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:lightgreen;
        }
    </style></em>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div><label for=" abc">name
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value="">
        </label></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]